# Как понять, в чем проблема системы, если перепробовал уже все, что можно? (НТ)

Tags: jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование, микросервисы, нагрузка

Есть система, микросервисная архитектура.
Если вкратце,  то с генератора запросы поступают на агент, затем в топики кафки, забираются адаптером,  передаются в ядро, оттуда в бд, соответственно ответ  возвращается через ядро и отправляется в адаптер, все это ждбс коннекты, оттуда в сервис печатных форм по ресту, обратно в кафку и через агент поступает ответ в виде хмля. Запрос ассинхронный. Выдает 300 рпс по всему контуру агент - агент. При необходимых - 500. Пробовал нагружать отдельно каждый компонент, адаптер. Ядро в связке с бд, сервисы пф, но результата не дало. Джметр и генератор нагрузки исключил, так как пробовал тесты локастом, распределенное тестирование с двух генераторов, тестирование через агент, то есть минуя дефолтный генератор нагрузки.

Куда смотреть, в чем может быть проблема? Какие параметры системы покрутить, возможно есть какие то идеи, как можно это дело оптимизировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интегрированная система в которой более одного компонента работает на скорости самого медленного.

Просто эмулируйте предполагаемую нагрузку на каждый компонент и когда найдете тот, который тормозит обработку до 300 рпс определите причину.

Наиболее часто встречающиеся:

1. "Дефолтная" "девелоперская" конфигурация сервера приложений, базы, кафки, и т.д. Каждый из этих компонентов имеет "production" конфигурацию и всякие инструкции для хайлоада. То же самое касается базы.
2. Банальная нехватка ресурсов (процессор, память, сеть, диск и т.д.). Проверьте что всему всего хватает, если нету интегрированной APM системы - гляньте на [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
3. Подключите профайлер типа [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) - он покажет где приложение проводит больше всего времени.
4. Подключите хотя бы встроенный мониторинг "медленных запросов" ([slow query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html)) и дедлоков на базе